# discord.py :: Message from bot is being sent twice

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the bit of code I have for adding a word to a profanity filter:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Head Honcho", "Discord Moderator")
async def addfilter(ctx, word):
    if word.lower() in bannedWords:
        await ctx.send(f"`{word}` is already in the profanity filter.")
    else:
        bannedWords.append(word.lower())

        with open("./config.json", "r+") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data["bannedWords"] = bannedWords
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
            f.truncate()

        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"`{word}` was added to the profanity filter.")
```

Whenever a word is trying to be added a second time, the bot will delete the message and say "f"`{word}` is already in the profanity filter." which it does fine, but for some reason it's sending it two times instead of just once. I can't see what I did wrong / what I'm missing. Could someone possibly show me what's causing this to happen?

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was wrong. Btw, there doesn't seem to be anything erroneous with your code actually. I can't see any reason for it sending the same message twice. Do you have an on_message event that might trigger the same message for some reason?

Comment: That was it! I went into my on_message section and removed an error, seems to be working now! Thank you very much!